# Any way to take multiple snapshots (sequentially) with different exposure times in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to take multiple snapshots squentially with different exposure times from an attached USB camera. However, upon changing the exposure time before each aquisition, the exposure time remains the same as that for the first snapshot as can been seen by looking at the image (even though cap.get() still returns the new exposure time).  Furthermore, the camera doesn't turn off when using .release().  Perhaps a driver issue?  The result is the same with the attached webcam on my Dell.

openCV v3.4.2 on Python v3.7.0

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
exp = cap.get(15)
width = cap.get(3)
height = cap.get(4)
print(f'original exporsure {exp:1}')

cap.set(15,-5) #set first exposure
ret, frame = cap.read() #get a single frame
print(f'exposure 1 {cap.get(15):1}')
cv2.imshow('1',frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cap.set(15,-10) #set second exposure
ret2, frame2 = cap.read()
print(f'exposure 2 {cap.get(15):1}')
cv2.imshow('2',frame2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I can't remember where I read it, but I think I read you must turn off "auto-exposure" as well as set a manual one. I may be wrong - I often am!